# How to save an online jpg in the asset folder?

Tags: android, imageview

I have an app that uses an imageview from the web, i've used this site:
http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/imageview-with-loading-spinner-t49439.html

When i have an internet connection it works fine, but wihtout not, so my question is, is there an option that i download the image one time (every night at 00.00) and that i can show the image from my asset?

I hope you understand me, if you have any question please ask me.
I hope you can help me.

Gaauwe

Answer (score 1):

You can download and save it in the application files directory (or other directory, on SD card for example) see [data storage options here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html), not in assets folder. The assets folder is packed and signed  with the APK.

Regarding download, it should not be hard, you can set an alarm for a specific time using [alarm manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and add some [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) or [broadcast receiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to handle the alarm and download the file.

Comment: How would the shared preferences look like? Could you write an example for me?

Comment: I didn't mention shared preferences. And I don't have android SDK on this computer, so no, sorry.

Comment: But can I also delete that file that I.made on the SD card, yes, how do you do that than?

Comment: I gave you all the relevant links. I don't want to write code I'm not sure about. look at the link - data storage option.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... You cant save it in assets. You can save it as SharedPreference or in SQLiteDatabase (array of bytes then decode as bitmap it each time whether there is net connection or not) or as file on the SD.  And of course you have to renew the image you have stored each time you download it (at that 00.00 time). Look around for decoding and encoding bitmap images to arrays, or renew the file on the SD.